# How to append the question and its answer into the 2D array setofquestions[]. how to check whether the answer the user gave is correct

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm creating a quiz and want to know how to append to a 2D array and how to compare answers in the 2D array with user inputs.

This part of the code should allow the user to add their own questions and then append the queston and answer to the 2D array.

```
def addQuestion(self):
        questionM = str(input("Please enter your questions:" ))
        answerM = str(input("is the answer True or False?: "))
        setofquestions.append(questionM)
        setofquestions.append(answerM)
        print(len(setofquestions))
        a.runQuiz
```

This part of the code should ask the question and check if the answer is correct

```
def askQuestion(self):
        QS = random.choice(setofquestions)
        print(QS[0:1])
        answer = str(input("True or False?: "))
        if bool(answer) == setofquestions[0][1]:
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

setofquestions = [["4 x 8 = 32",True],["There are 8 continents",False],["This is a Quiz",True],["You are a parrot",False]]
```